# Tail Recursion java

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

I am working on finding the largest prime factor of any given number. The code below works fine for most numbers until I input the number I want which is 600851475143. Once I do this I get stack overflow. I have been reading up on tail recursion and from what I know I should have implemented it right. Yet, I still receive the stack overflow error despite it. Where am I going wrong when it comes to implementing tail recursion?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LargestPrimeFactor
{
    static long number;
    static long answer;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println( "Enter number to find its largest prime factor");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        number = input.nextLong();

        answer = largestPrime(number);
        System.out.println("The largest prime of " + number + " is " + answer);
    }

    private static long largestPrime(long n)
    {
        n = n-1;    
        if(n % 2 != 0 & number % n == 0 )
        {   
            return n;
        }
        else
        {           
            return largestPrime(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While Java does support tail-recursive calls I don't believe it currently optimizes them. You might consider using [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: your doing it just fine, but your java compiler doesn't optimize the tail call into a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in the if condition you're doing `&` when you probably meant to do `&&`. And second, your implementation is incorrect. Try to run it on 18 (largest prime is 3) and see that it returns `9` which is obviously not prime.

As for the stackoverflow, since there's no condition that restrict `n > 1` in some cases the calculation will continue with `-1, -2, -3,...` until you'll get stackoverflow...

And last, the JVM does *not* support tail-recursion optimization, but even if it did - you'll almost always be better with an iterative solution because unlike recursive solutions - it doesn't open a new frame on the stack for every recursive call (because there are no recursive calls - it runs in a loop).

**Edit**

- To find the largest prime factor you can start with `n/2` and go down
  (minus one each iteration).
- The definition of a prime number `p` is: `p > 1` and `p` can be divided only by itself (and `1`). Use this definition and write an iterative method `boolean isPrime(int num)`
- now use the previous two bullet-point and combine them to write a recursive method that finds the largest prime. I didn't want to implement it in order not to ruin your fun :)

Comment: Isn't the point of tail recursion that the old stack frame is overwritten with the new one? I can see it being less efficient due to having to perform more writes to get a "clean" frame (which I'm not sure that's true, I lack the expertise). But saying it "opens a new frame" seems inaccurate unless it really does need to reset everything.

Comment: Yeah I was running an iterative implementation but I noticed that it is taking a while to compute the final number. That leaves with two questions. At what point did I implement it wrong so that it gives 9 which is not prime. Also, what may you suggest so that it calculates faster?

Comment: @ChrisHayes *any* call to method opens a new frame on the stack, even with optimization you can't get rid of the "push"s and the "pop"s that it requires. If you'd like a good reading on the subject: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/tail-call-optimization-and-java/240167044

Comment: @SEV19957 I'll add another paragraph for that.

Comment: @alfasin Yes this is just what I needed. I could care less about getting the number for project euler. The whole reason is to learn through the process of creating it and push myself to figure it out. Thanks for saving the fun part of implementation for me :)